# Neo4j, get all relationships between a set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've a query that fetches nodes based on a property

```
MATCH (c { type: 'sometype' })
WITH c LIMIT 100
RETURN c
```

all I want is to also fetch all the relations between nodes in the resultset, on IRC someone told me to use:

```
MATCH (c { type: 'sometype'])
WITH c LIMIT 100
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r]-()
RETURN c, r
```

but that will include relationships from node c to nodes outside the resultset which in my case (some hundred thousand relationships) could create very big useless resultset or performance issues)

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alex,

Another way to approach this is this query:

```
MATCH (c {type : 'sometype'})-[r:*0..1]-(d {type : 'sometype'})
WITH c, collect(r) as rs
RETURN c, rs
```

This allows for the case where there are no relationships of this sort.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: Thanks, Michael! I was full of typos on this answer.

Comment: That r:*0..1 makes the relationship optional?

Comment: Yes. It will succeed with zero or one relationships.

Comment: I'm getting this error - Invalid input '*': expected whitespace or a rel type name. Has something changed in version 3.0 ?

Comment: How can I return the type of each relation in 'rs' ?

Comment: Use the function type(rs).

Comment: this will be executed forever. better aproach to use optional match
Also here you cant limit number of (c) nodes

Answer (score 5):

I guess there are multiple ways to do that. One approach is to find all nodes for the given type and build a collection out of them (`cs`). Then match again that group, this time with outgoing relationships to any node and filter that to make sure the endnode is in `cs`:

```
MATCH (c {type:'sometype'})
WITH collect(c) as cs
MATCH (x {type:'sometype'})-[r]->(y)
WHERE y in cs
RETURN startNode(r).name, endNode(r).name
```

Don't know your graph model, but I think it could be a good idea to refactor the property `type='sometype'` into a label `sometype`. In this case the query would look like this:

```
MATCH (c:Group1)   
WITH collect(c) as cs
MATCH (x:Group1)-[r]->(y)
WHERE y in cs
RETURN startNode(r).name, endNode(r).name
```

Answer (score 3):

This is straight forward.

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE a.type = 'foo' AND b.type = 'foo'
RETURN DISTINCT r
```

You could equally use the new syntax:

```
MATCH (a { type : 'foo' }) -[r] - (b {type : 'foo'})
RETURN DISTINCT r
```

If you prefer it.

Comment: Right but to perform, labels + index would be needed.

Comment: Yes, ideally you should make your type into a label. THen it will be super fast.

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you used labels instead of a property for type. This will make your queries very fast using schema indexes.

```
MATCH (a:SOMETYPE) -[r] - (b :SOMETYPE) RETURN DISTINCT r
```

Comment: I am also thought that because label is not a optional one and wecan make it as a public data...

Answer (score 1):

The most fastest way that i found is:

```
 MATCH (n:NodeName {param:"7"})
        with n
        skip 0
        limit 5
        MATCH n-[r]->(k)
        with n,k,r
```

Also you can decrease execution time if for example instead of n,k,r will use ***n.data,r.data, k.data***

This was tested on Neo4j 2.3

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the matches necessary, you can try this:

```
MATCH (c { type: 'sometype'})
WITH c LIMIT 100
WITH COLLECT(c) as cNodes
UNWIND cNodes as c1
MATCH (c1)-[r]->(c2)
WHERE c2 in cNodes
RETURN c1, TYPE(r) as rel, c2
```

As others have mentioned, a match without labels isn't recommended since all nodes must be scanned, so as the size of the db grows, the query will get slower and slower. Use a label on the initial match if possible, and if there's an index on the label and its `type` property, this can be a very fast query.

Answer (score 0):

There's a APOC function for this - [`apoc.algo.cover`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.algo/apoc.algo.cover/).

```sql
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.type = "sometype"
WITH collect(id(n)) as nodes
CALL apoc.algo.cover(nodes)
YIELD rel
RETURN  startNode(rel), rel, endNode(rel);
```