# get all relationships for a node with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to find out all the incoming and outgoing relationships for a node. I tried couple of queries suggested in other questions but not having much luck. These are the two I tried

```
MATCH (a:User {username: "user6"})-[r*]-(b)
RETURN a, r, b
```

I only have 500 nodes and it runs forever. I gave up after an hour.

I tried this

```
MATCH (c:User {username : 'user6'})-[r:*0..1]-(d)
WITH c, collect(r) as rs
RETURN c, rs
```

But I get this error

```
WARNING: Invalid input '*': expected whitespace or a rel type name (line 1, column 35 (offset: 34))
"MATCH (c {username : 'user6'})-[r:*0..1]-(d)"
```

What would be correct way to get all the relationships for a node?

I'm using version 3.0.3

Comment: Best way of doing this query is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42833702/277345

Comment: Remove the colon in your second query. It should be `MATCH (c:User {username : 'user6'})-[r*0..1]-(d)`. The colon is for labels only.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The simplest way to get all relationships for a single node is like this:

```
MATCH (:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-()
RETURN r
```

Comment: but how do you get all the nodes that are related deeper

Comment: `MATCH (:User {username: 'user6'})-[r*1..3]-()
RETURN r` will find nodes that are related deeper 1 to 3 times.

Comment: Since this answer is no longer valid for 3.1 and above, it should be updated accordingly. For recent versions, please check answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/42206827/6515775  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54557950/6515775

Answer (score 37):

The above solution doesn't return a graph representation in 3.1 anymore. Instead below solution should work

```
MATCH (a:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-(b)
RETURN r, a, b
```

This was answered in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971237/cypher-query-to-get-all-relationship-for-a-node-doesnt-return-graphical-represe/41972253#41972253)

Comment: yea, apparently the [r*1..3] feature was deprecated. Know off the top of your head how to query more than 1 degree of depth now?

Answer (score 13):

Most of these answers will work just fine, but if like me, you also need the name of the relationship itself, you need to wrap `r` with `type()`:

```
MATCH (a:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-(b)
RETURN type(r), a, b
```

Answer (score 7):

```
MATCH (n1:Node1)-[:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]-(OtherNodes)
RETURN n1, OtherNodes
```

This will get Node1 and its relations with other nodes

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This query will show all relationships and connected nodes for a single Person node filtered by their email, as a graph.

```
MATCH(n1:Person {email: 'someone@somewhere.com'})-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c)
RETURN n1, r1, r2, b, c LIMIT 500
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Fetch all nodes:

```
START n=node () RETURN n
```

OR

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

2. Displays the nodes and the relationships:

```
MATCH (n) MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN n,r
```

OR

```
START n=node() MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m
```

3. Match nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH (a:Policy)-[:APPLIES_TO]-(Cluster) WHERE a.name = "pol-1nils" RETURN a, Cluster
```

4. Get all object of particular nodes:

```
MATCH (list:Policy) RETURN list
```

5. Bound to the entities between two nodes:

```
MATCH (a:WorkLoad)-[b:APPLIES_TO]->(c:Policy) WHERE c.name = "shamshad" RETURN a,b,c;
```

Comment: consider adding small explanation

Answer (score 0):

For 5.3 Neo4j, this is working. To get the nodes and relationship

```
Match (n)-[r]->(m) Return n,r,m
```