# cypher query to get all relationship for a node doesn't return graphical representation in 3.1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I upgraded neo4j community edition from 3.0.3 to 3.1 and this query doesn't return graphical representation of all the relationships for this node anymore.

```
MATCH (:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-()
RETURN r
```

Any reasons why it wouldn't work in 3.1?

Comment: No reason that I can see. You're sure such a node exists, and that it has relationships?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it doesn't return graphical representation anymore in browser

Comment: I think you'll only see it if nodes are returned. You'll need to add a variable on at least one of the nodes and return that too.

Comment: What if you don't know all the nodes it is connected to. I guess that is the whole idea of the query to find out about all the relationships of node. Why it has stopped working in 3.1?

Comment: You do know what it's connected to. It's right there in your match. Just put variables for the start and end nodes, and return those along with the relationship. I haven't tried a query like this in < 3.1, since nearly every query where I was interested in viewing the graphical view returned nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the browser requires you to return nodes in order to see the graphical view. Just add variables on your start and end nodes and return them.

```
MATCH (a:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-(b)
RETURN r, a, b
```

Comment: Yeah that works. But still would have been nice to know why previous query worked fine 3.0

Answer (score 0):

'r' refers to a relationship on its own. To return a graph you need the node(s) as well.

Try

```
MATCH graph = (a:User {username: 'user6'})-[r]-(b)
RETURN graph
```