# py2neo query subgraph from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I want to query a subgraph from a large graph data base with a given source. Say I want the top 25 neighbors of a given node, along with all the relations among this set of nodes, how should my query be?

At the moment I have:

```
MATCH (source {label:'source'}) -[:relation]-> (neighbors)
RETURN source,neighbors
LIMIT 25
```

This works in the neo4j browser, returning the 26 nodes as well as all the existing relations among those nodes. However, when I try execute the same query via py2neo:

```
py2neo.cypher.execute(query)
```

it only returns 26 nodes along with the 25 direct edge connections between the source and the 25 neighbors, which makes sense. But I wonder why there is a difference between the browser result versus the py2neo result. And how I can achieve the same result with all the edge connections returned.

In general, I would like to know the following smaller questions:

- how to append a single node to a list of nodes in neo4j? e.g. nlist = neighbors + node
- how to return all the relationships between two sets of nodes? e.g. return (a in nlist) -[:relation]-> (b in nlist)

Edits:

To visualize, I want the resulting graph to be something like this

[image: subgraph]

rather than a star graph like this

[image: star]

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Are you visualizing the results in Neo4j Browser using the graph visualization mode? If true, try changing to text mode for more precision representation.

Comment: Also, can you explain a bit more about the difference between results shown in neo4j browser and the result via py2neo?

Comment: Indeed I was viewing in the graph mode. And when I change to text mode it looks like I get the same results as I get from py2neo I believe. I have added a few more edits to illustrate what I mean by the difference.

Comment: I believe the answer for your first question can be `MATCH (source {label:'source'}) -[:relation]-> (neighbors)
WITH collect(source) + collect(neighbors) as all
UNWIND all AS nodes
RETURN nodes`. Right?

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I needed to start, with some extra tweaking and I find a good answer for the second question from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203804/neo4j-get-all-relationships-between-a-set-of-nodes
Would you like to reply via an answer and I can edit and accept this as a solution? Thanks for the input, this is a very good example for using collect I guess.

Comment: Yes, I will do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the difference between Neo4j Browser and py2neo result: probably you are using the graph visualization mode with the option "Connect result nodes" enable. Try disabling (below image) it or change the visualization mode to "Text", for example.

[image: Graph visualization options]

About the Cypher query, you can use `collect()` to merge `source` and `neighbors`:

```
MATCH (source {label:'source'})-[:relation]->(neighbors)
WITH collect(source) + collect(neighbors) as all
UNWIND all AS nodes
RETURN nodes
```

In order to return the all the edges between two sets of nodes (in this case from set to itself), refer to this post:[Neo4j, get all relationships between a set of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203804/neo4j-get-all-relationships-between-a-set-of-nodes)

Then the subgraph is returned with the Cypher query

```
MATCH (source {label:'source'})-[:relation]->(neighbors)
WITH collect(distinct source) + collect(neighbors) as all
UNWIND all AS nodes
MATCH (nodes)-[:relation]->(nei)
WHERE nei in nodes
RETURN nodes,nei
```